# Regular expression - return string after equal sign and before a pipe

Tags: regex

I attempted to resolve this on my own, but I need some help.

I have a strong that is located in my syslogs - and while I know grep would be easier, I have my reasons for building a regular expression.

For example:   `somerandomstufffilter-category=Web_Advertisements|andhereis more random stuff`

In that garbled mess, there is an exact string `'filter-category=Web_Advertisements|'`

I created this regex:     `(filter-category=).*?(?=["|"])`

Which pulls the exact string I want, and up to the pipe. Instead of giving me the entire string, I only want everything after the equal sign (and not include it in my match), and before the pipe.

Right now I am getting:    `'filter-category=Web_Advertisements'`
What I want to get is:   `'Web_Advertisements'` on its own. The trick is that whatever follows filter-category, can be anything, not just Web-Advertisements. That is why it MUST end with the first pipe it encounters.

Comment: +1 - for the earnest attempt!

Comment: Regex engines differ in capability, and in syntax.  If you add a tag (or just include it in the question) describing which regex engine/environment (perl/php/egrep/javascript/etc) you're using, people can give you better answers.

Comment: @ Gus, thank you for your input. I will keep that in mind in the future. I was not aware of the engine I was using until the question was posed to me.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to capture `filter-category=`, so drop the `()`.
2. You don't need to use a lookahead here, so drop the `(?=...)`.
3. By the way, you were misusing character classes by writing `["|"]`—that would have meant you were going to match either a double-quote `"` or a pipe `|`.

Here's what you want:

```
filter-category=(.*?)\|
```

Comment: I tried to use that, but it returns 'filter-category=Web_Advertisements|'      Also, I am trying to find the pipe, and end my search. Based on my understanding, I do need the lookahead so it does not include it. I would be less confused with a more concrete example.

Comment: What implementation? Perl? PHP? It must be returning the total match, `$0`. An alternative, then, _is_ to use lookaround assertions: `(?<=filter-category=)(.*?)(?=\|)`, but I don't know if whatever you're using supports lookbehind assertions.

Comment: @Jason - are you extracting the captured group $1?

Comment: Javascript expressions - This is for a SIEM tool. I am using http://www.roblocher.com/technotes/regexp.aspx  this site to test, and I also just put that string in my SIEM tool, where it failed.

Comment: @He Was - No, I am not. I haven't gotten that far yet, as ideally I am going to build a large set of report parameters using regex. So, if I want to see all my web traffic with a certain category, I can run this regex on the 'filter-category' part..

Comment: Ah. Well, assuming it uses the Javascript regex engine, Javascript doesn't support lookbehind assertions. Your _only_ option now is to find a way to output the _first_ captured match. In regular expressions, the "zeroth" match is the entire match, the "first" match is the first parenthesized "capture group", the "second" match is the second, etc. Whatever you're using is outputting the zeroth, currently.

Comment: @acheong87 - Thank you for your help. It appears based on our back and forth, that I have generated the best match then during my own attempt to resolve. I'll remove the parenthesis but it will have no effect on the regex since I am not using a language to grab the "groups".

Answer (score 0):

<del>acheong87's answer could include pipes in the capture... if it's greedy and there is more than one pipe, it will capture everything up to the last pipe.</del>

Try

`filter-category=([^\|]*)\|`

Like acheong87's answer, this will match the *whole* of

filter-category=Web_Advertisements|

from which you have to extract the part you want to keep, captured into $1

Comment: Hm, but that's why I used a non-greedy quantifier: `.*?`.